# How to import python module in the same directory in vim?

Tags: python, vim, import, directory

I am using `Vim 8.2` on `Windows 10`

Here is the sample about my directory:

```
Python_project/
|__pycache__/
|venv/
    |--Hello.py
    |--main.py
    |--another_file.py
```

I want to `import Hello` in `main.py` like in [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) but it seems not to work in Vim.

Are there Vim settings to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "not work"? Can you be a little more specific?

If your `main.py` looks like

```
import Hello
```

Your code will work in any environment.

If what you wrote was `import Hello.py`, that would be your problem. Just remove the file extension